# could someone please explain why this list is redefining itself like this?

Tags: python

```
>>> def hello(l):
k=l
k.append('s')
return l

>>> hello(['hello'])
['hello', 's']
```

Just a strange occurrence i found in python3.4.1 I'm sure it has a reason but I don't understand it.

Comment: what do you mean redefining itself? What part of the result didn't you expect?

Comment: Because changing a mutable object inside a function can impact the caller, and here you have create a reference to `l` with name `k` and change the `k` so actually you changed the `l`.

Comment: The variables `k` and `l` both refer to the same list, which you're modifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append modifies the referenced object in-place, instead or returning a new one. Even if you type k=l, the append method will modify the underlying referenced list, so both k and l will have the value ['hello', 's']